# infinite loop using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I am creating a project that updates my data in firebase, however I have console logged the data and its constantly coming through.

How do I stop the loop essentially so that it doesn't crash.

```
import "./App.css";

import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import { Container, Divider, Card } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Cards from "./components/Cards/index";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AppProvider } from "./Context/Context.js";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import {} from "firebase/firestore";
import * as FirestoreService from "./components/service/firebase";
import firebase from "@firebase/app-compat";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [cloudFucntions, setCloudFucntions] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setUser(user);

      const unsubscribe = FirestoreService.getCloudFunctionItems(
        (querySnapshot) => {
          const updatedCloundFunctions = querySnapshot.docs.map((docSnapshot) =>
            docSnapshot.data()
          );
          setCloudFucntions(updatedCloundFunctions);
          console.log(updatedCloundFunctions);
        },
        (error) => setError("list-item-get-fail")
      );
      return unsubscribe;
    });
  }, [cloudFucntions]);

  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Header />

          <Divider horizontal section>
            Cloud Function Monitor
          </Divider>

          {user ? (
            <Card.Group itemsPerRow="4">
              {cloudFucntions &&
                cloudFucntions.map((cloudFunction) => {
                  return (
                    <Cards
                      key={cloudFunction.id}
                      cloudFunction={cloudFunction}
                    ></Cards>
                  );
                })}
            </Card.Group>
          ) : (
            <h2> Please sign in using the button in the top right. </h2>
          )}
        </Container>
      </div>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Image of console...]

I have tried using an empty array and not passing anything through however i get the errors:
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `CardContent`, expected a ReactNode.
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: Your useEffect is taking dependency as 'cloudFucntions' and inside useEffect you are setting state of which is changing the value of 'cloudFucntions' and when value change it will re trigger  the useEffect and process stuck in infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't generally use a dependency for an effect that the effect ultimately updates, this is what leads to render looping. For the `useEffect` hook, `cloudFucntions` isn't referenced at all in the callback, so it's not a dependnecy. With firebase connections it's more common to use a mounting `useEffect` hook, i.e. an empty dependency array.

I see also that the component doesn't unsubscribe from the `onAuthStateChanged` check. Since the the second cloud functions fetching doesn't appear to be dependent on the `user`, you should split these into their own effects and subscription clean ups.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = firebase.auth()
    .onAuthStateChanged((user) => setUser(user));
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = FirestoreService.getCloudFunctionItems(
    (querySnapshot) => {
      const updatedCloundFunctions = querySnapshot
        .docs
        .map((docSnapshot) => docSnapshot.data());
      setCloudFucntions(updatedCloundFunctions);
    },
    (error) => setError("list-item-get-fail")
  );
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

This only means that `key={cloudFunction.id}` isn't a unique enough id to be used as a React key. React keys ***must*** be unique among siblings. ***Don't use the array index as key unless you've no other choice.*** It's not recommended.

If your cloud function objects have duplicate ids, or there are duplicate cloud functions being returned you should fix this in the backend. If this isn't something you can resolve in the backend then you'll need to generate unique ids when you receive them in the frontend.

Example:

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

...

const updatedCloundFunctions = querySnapshot
  .docs
  .map((docSnapshot) => ({
    guid: uuidV4(), // <-- generate your own GUID
    ...docSnapshot.data(),
  }));
setCloudFucntions(updatedCloundFunctions);

...

cloudFucntions.map((cloudFunction) => {
  return (
    <Cards
      key={cloudFunction.guid} // <-- use your GUID here as key
      cloudFunction={cloudFunction}
    />
  );
})}
```

> ```
> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop children supplied to CardContent, expected a ReactNode.
> ```

> ```
> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.
> ```

For each of these we'd need to see the `Cards` component I suspect. The warnings are with regard to a `CartContent` component it seems. You can add the `Cards` component and other relevant code, along with any propTypes definitions and we can further refine answer, or you can post a new question on SO since these are rather extra-curricular to the issue of the render looping and React keys.

Comment: Splitting them up pretty much sorted it, without having to ignore anything ! Thank you for your help Drew! really appreciate  you going into detail- will have to post another question for the other issues :)

Comment: @kkongkk Welcome. If/when you post any new questions for the other issues, feel free to ping (@ me) here in a comment with a link to the new question. Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect dependency on the useEffect. The call to `setCloudFucntions` will retrigger useEffect (because it sets `cloudFucntions`)

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    ...
          setCloudFucntions(updatedCloundFunctions);
    ...
  }, [cloudFucntions]);
```

You don't need it, your effect does not use `cloudFucntions`.

The warning is concerning the key in the render, it seems that cloudFunction.id may not be unique.

You could do this

```js
cloudFucntions.map((cloudFunction, idx) => {
  return (
    <Cards
      key={idx}
      cloudFunction={cloudFunction}
    ></Cards>
  )
```

Comment: can i leave it as an empty array

Comment: I couldn't see anything else that needs to go in the array, but React tells you if there is something that needs to go in (a warning in devtools and on the terminal where  you start the app).

Comment: thanks!! this loop stopped but i get the following  error when i do pass an empty array: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: Yes, that's a different problem - I can't really advise without seeing more of the app. The reason you didn't see the warning before was because React was too busy infinitely looping.